# Stop fadeOut if the mouse enters the logo

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this fiddle.

**http://jsfiddle.net/LTSSx/15/**

Right now it fades out when the mouse leaves. But when the mouse leaves and enters the logo again, I want to clear timeout. But when I clear the timeout, the function stops working because on startup there is no timer. Help me please thanks.

```
$('.logo').mouseenter(function(){
    $('.bubble-container').fadeIn();
});

$('.logo').mouseleave(function(){
    setTimeout(function() {
         $('.bubble-container').fadeOut();
    },1000);
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pretty sure this'll work. Just put the timeout into a global variable, so clearTimeout can access it.

```
var fadeOutTimeout;

$('.logo').mouseenter(function(){
    clearTimeout(fadeOutTimeout);
    $('.bubble-container').fadeIn();
});

$('.logo').mouseleave(function(){
    fadeOutTimeout = setTimeout(function() {
         $('.bubble-container').fadeOut();
   },1000);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

fiddle of it working: http://jsfiddle.net/LTSSx/18/

```
var timer = '';
$('.logo').mouseenter(function(){
    clearTimeout(timer);
    $('.bubble-container').fadeIn();
});

$('.logo').mouseleave(function(){
    timer = setTimeout(function() {
         $('.bubble-container').fadeOut();
    },1000);
});
```

Comment: oic, you want to stop the setTimeout

Comment: Rhok stole my answer and got the check..lame